# Retrieve logger in log4rs

Tags: logging, rust

I am a C++ developer and explore Rust. I am used to the log4cxx library and try to find my way around in its Rust counterpart log4rs.

I created a library that parses an xml into a struct. Logging is done with the `log::` macros which provide the implementation agnostic interface.

Now how would I go about retrieving a log4rs logger and passing that to the object. It seems that all the log macros use the root logger which kind of breaks the advantage of using log4rs in the first place.

### Solution:

Thanks to @Jmb for the answer. Here is an example of what I intended to do (crate name: `test_crate`):

in main.rs

```
  // configure log4cxx logger
  let stdout = ConsoleAppender::builder()
    .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::new("{d} - {m}{n}")))
    .build();

  let config = Config::builder()
    .appender(Appender::builder().build("stdout", Box::new(stdout)))
    .logger(Logger::builder().build("test_crate::my_module", LevelFilter::Trace))
    .build(Root::builder().appender("stdout").build(LevelFilter::Warn))
    .unwrap();

  log4rs::init_config(config).unwrap();
```

and calling the `log::...` macros from the within the `my_module` module in the `lib.rs`

*note: Ideally the logger should be configured in a separate logging config file to configure the logger at runtime.*

Comment: The log macros use a different logger for each Rust module. Or you can use e.g. `info!(target: "foo", "message");` to target a different logger.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you add an answer I can mark it as resolved. Further: What is the convention of the names that log uses? If you could point  me to the correct doc that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the log macros use a different logger for each Rust module: [*A target is a string which defaults to the module path of the location of the log request, though that default may be overridden.*](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.14/log/). You can use e.g. `info!(target: "foo", "message");` to target a different logger.